# Converting FrameLayout from two images into one image

Tags: android

I have try convering with bitmap but the problem is that the image look bed here is what i did :

```
 submitPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            customImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            customImage.buildDrawingCache();

            //Bitmap bit =Bitmap.createBitmap(customImage.getWidth(), customImage.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            //Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bit);
            //personPhoto.draw(canvas);
            Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap( customImage.getDrawingCache());
            customImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            Intent intent=new Intent(OnPhotoTakedActivity.this,OnPhotoSubmit.class);
            intent.putExtra("bitmap",scaleDownBitmap(bitmap,120,getApplicationContext()));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

and in the next activity :

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap=intent.getExtras().getParcelable("bitmap");

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I tryed all the codes on this and other webs but still the image look bad
thanks any way.

Comment: the image looks bad is not really helpful maybe describe it more or make pictures how it's looking right now and how it should look

Comment: i am putting in a hd image but the converting is pixelized and i want it to stay the same

Comment: The first image is like this :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-MkXyc2eUanLVBXZkVEck4yOTUzeWE5SHRuRV95VTgxTVpv/view
and the image convert to this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-MkXyc2eUanY1ZDSlgyX3ozQTJoS1RkSWstcllzNkFTTV9R/view